# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0,0) into shape (224,224)

Tags: python, numpy

I get the above error when assigning images I read from the folder to the batch_xs file.

This is my code.

```
batch_xs = np.zeros(shape=(1,224, 224))
for index in range(100):
    for img in glob.glob("Validation/*.jpg"):
        n= cv2.imread(img,0)
        batch_xs[index, :, :] = n[112:3, 112:3]
```

How can I solve it

Comment: could you please add the error log?

Comment: `n[112:3, 112:3]` this is wrong. Please share the dimension of `img`. If it's more than 336 in both `x` and `y` then you can use `n[112:3*112]` but it's hard to tell without knowing what you want.

Comment: Can you give a small example with some values from the `imread` result, and what should happen to `batch_xs` as a result?

Comment: An indexing slice like `112:3` produces a size 0 dimension.  That do you really want?  To fit in the `batch_xs[0,:,:]` is has to be a (224,224) shape array.  Tell us about `n`?

Comment: I want to read 100 *.jpg images from the folder with a size of 224x224 and throw them into a batch_xs as a numpy. Then I will use them for prediction.

Comment: predict = model.prediction(batch_xs)